# orderTotal and orderId inside tpl_checkout_success_default - zen-cart

Tags: php, zen-cart

any ideas how to get orderTotal and orderId inside the tpl_checkout_success_default for the conversions tracking purposes ?

So far it looks like order id can be accessed by using this variable $zv_orders_id but how to get order total ?

will this code work:

`$orders_query = "SELECT * FROM zen_orders WHERE orders_id = " . $zv_orders_id ." LIMIT 1";
$orders = $db->Execute($orders_query);
$order_total = $orders->fields['order_total'];`

many thanks,
cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look in `/includes/modules/pages/checkout_success/header_php.php`

in there you will see the queries already being run by `zencart` to do with your order, and id say its already pulling out the info you want.

so you just need to set said data you need to a variable that you can then use in your `tpl_checkout_success_default.php` file.

eg, something like `$customer_has_gv_balance`, you will see where it is set in the hearder file and then used in the template file

heres something i found in `order.php` that would almost do it as is:

```
$order_total_query = "select text, value
                             from " . TABLE_ORDERS_TOTAL . "
                             where orders_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'
                             and class = 'ot_total'";

$order_total = $db->Execute($order_total_query);
```

Comment: i looked a bit more and i dont think it is pulled out , as what you want is in orders_total table not just orders. so you want to make a query like this: (see above)

Comment: great but how to access value from $order_total ? $order_total->value ? cheers

Comment: what about $order_summary variable ?

Comment: yeah maybe its in there too, just try to put in there var_dump($variable); to printout what its storing.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple tracking code like one used for a shopping comparison site, I've used the following for the order ID and order amount.  Use these in the tpl_checkout_success.php page

Order ID:

```
echo $zv_orders_id;
```

Use this select statement:

```
$to_send_sql = 'select REPLACE (text,"$","") text from orders_total where orders_id = '.$zv_orders_id.' and class = "ot_subtotal"';

$to_send= $db->Execute($to_send_sql);
```

Order amount:

```
echo $to_send->fields['text'];
```

Hope this helps someone!